# Name of all the children objects in a three.js object

Tags: three.js

i want to get the var name of all the children objects in a three.js object and then store them in an array.

object has a property .children but this gets an array of all the data not just an array of the objects variable names
this is what i have tried but comes up empty

```
var arrayHead = headGroup.children;
           var testarray =[];


            for (var i = 0; i < testarray.length; i++) {
                testarray.push(arrayHead[i].name);

            }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. The site works this way: You search online for what you need to understand to build a solution. If your solution is not perfect and you have problems with it, then you ask for support here. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `arrayHead` is of type `Object3D()`

```
var testarray = [];
arrayHead.traverse ( function (child) {
    testarray.push( child.name );
} );
```